# minium jars needed to compile JavaEE application which will be deployed on weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I want to write a ant script to compile Java source code of our application. I know I need to add WEB-INF/classes and jars in WEB-INF/lib to classpath, I want to know what other jar files I need and where to find them

Comment: we are using weblogic 11g

Comment: I mean those JavaEE jars contained in weblogic such as servlet api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just include all javax.* jars  under %WEBLOGIC_HOME%/Modules

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using web logic server, you will get all the jars from its installation folder itself like Tomcat for example.

Comment: nope you do not need javaEE SDK as you are using web logic app server

Comment: Yes, it's not necessary.currently, I include all javax*.jar in classpath, and it works for me